# Liang - Game of Heads and tails

Tags: java, random

I'm quite stuck from a problem in the liang introduction to Java book - Here's the problem:

"Sixteen coins are placed in a 4-by-4 matrix with some face up and some face down. You can represent the state of the coins using a 4-by-4 matrix with values 0 (head) and 1 (tail). Here are some examples:

```
0000
0100
0000
0010
```

each state can also be repesented using a binary number (a concatenation of the above). Write a program that prompts the user to enter a number between 0 and 65,536 and displays the corresponding matrix - a balue of 7 would give 00000111.

My question is how would you verify that this was the case for 7 ? I'm not even that sure how to begin prototyping such a method  - perhaps int x = (int)Math.rand(1) and assign to each of the rows/cols?

Perhaps someone could give me some hints on where to start?

Comment: The question's introduction was a poorly-executed attempt to give you an idea of what binary values could represent in the real world (coins with heads/tails values). The real assignment here is to take a base-ten number and output it as a binary number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is essentially converting an integer in the range *[0, 65536]* to its binary representation. This can be done with [`Integer.toBinaryString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toBinaryString%28int%29). For instance,

```
Integer.toBinaryString(7);
```

would result in the string `111`. Now, we want the total length of the string to be *16*, so we need to pad with `0`s on the left to obtain `0000000000000111`. We can do something like:

```
String.format("%16s", Integer.toBinaryString(7)).replace(' ', '0');
```

which results in the string `0000000000000111`.

Once you have this, you can simply copy it into a 4x4 int (or boolean) array. Or, you can just print the data right off the bat,

```
String bin = String.format("%16s", Integer.toBinaryString(7)).replace(' ', '0');

for (int i = 0 ; i < 4 ; i++)
    System.out.println(bin.substring(4 * i, 4 * (i + 1)));
```

Output:

```
0000   
0000  
0000  
0111
```

Of course, you can replace that `7` with whatever integer you read form the user, but the idea is the same.

Comment: How exactly does String.format("%16s", Integer.toBinaryString(7)).replace(' ', '0'); work ?

I was going to take the approach of turning into a char array and then looping from a point subtracted by the initial length. I guess that's more verbose ?

Comment: @peter_gent `String.format("%16s", Integer.toBinaryString(7))` places white spaces in front of `Integer.toBinaryString(7)` until the total length is 16. We then replace all these white spaces with `0` with `.replace(' ', '0')`. You can read [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...)) to learn more.

Comment: System.out.println(bin.substring(4 * i, 4 * (i + 1))); This is also very interesting.... in other words it iterates through the substring from 4 : to 4*i+1. My implementation was to do 

for(int rows=0;rows<result.length;rows++){
                  for(int cols=0;cols<result.length;cols++){
                    result[rows][cols] = Character.getNumericValue(array[i]);
                    i++;
                  }
              }

Comment: @peter_gent `System.out.println(bin.substring(4 * i, 4 * (i + 1)))` essentially splits the `bin` string into chunks of 4, as `i` ranges from `0` to `3`. You can read about `substring` [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,%20int)).

Answer (score 0):

Since the actual program you are supposed to write to answer the question is: `Write a program that prompts the user to enter a number between 0 and 65,536 and displays the corresponding matrix - a value of 7 would give 00000111.`

This just sounds like a very convoluted way to say: "Convert decimal to binary and print":

```
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

...
public static void printBinaryRepOfDecimal() throws IOException {
    BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    System.out.println("Enter a number between 0 and 65,536:");
    String hex = bf.readLine();
    int i = Integer.parseInt(hex);  
    String by = Integer.toBinaryString(i);
    for (int i = 0; i < (16 - by.length); i++) {
        System.out.print("0");
    }
    System.out.println(by);
}
```

This will print the 16 bits of binary you want. Alternatively, convert the sample code to manipulate the string to suit your needs.